# Characterization of all the functions that satisfy $f(x) - f(y) \lt \epsilon$ with $x-y \lt \delta$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The question is to characterize all the functions such that, for any positive $\epsilon,$ there exist a $\delta \gt 0$ for which $f(x) - f(y) \lt \epsilon$ for all $x$ and $y$ such that $x-y \lt \delta.$

Clearly all the constant functions will trivially satisfy this. Also not for every continuous function it's true.

Any idea for the other functions ? How to think these type of problems ?

Thank you

Comment: Should this not be all the continuous functions?

Comment: If instead you have "there exists $\delta> 0$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta$" then this is the definition of [uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity).

Comment: For $f(x) = -x $ and $\epsilon = 1/2$, I didn't find any suitable$\delta \gt 0$, so I thought not all continuous functions are on that set. Can you find any suitable $\delta$ ?

Comment: To be clear, what does "$f(x) - f(y) \lt \epsilon$ with $x-y \lt \delta$" mean?  Do you mean that $f(x)-f(y)<\epsilon$ **for all** $x$ and $y$ such that $x-y<\delta$?  Or is $x$ fixed beforehand and you just mean for all such $y$?  Or something else?

Comment: For all $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $ x-y \lt \delta$, $f(x) - f(y) \lt \epsilon$ holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying this condition are exactly the increasing functions which are uniformly continuous.  That is, they are functions such that

1. $x\leq y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, and
2. for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|< \delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

In particular, for instance, this includes any differentiable function whose derivative is bounded and nonnegative.

To prove this characterization, first suppose $f$ satisfies your condition.  If $f$ is not increasing, then there are $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x<y$ but $f(x)>f(y)$.  Let $\epsilon=f(x)-f(y)$ and pick $\delta>0$ as in your condition.  Then $x-y<0<\delta$ but $f(x)-f(y)\not<\epsilon$, a contradiction.  Thus $f$ must be increasing.  Uniform continuity then follows immediately, since given $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ as in your condition, if $|x-y|<\delta$ we may assume without loss of generality that $x\geq y$ (otherwise swap $x$ and $y$) so then $x-y<\delta$ and thus $f(x)-f(y)<\epsilon$ and thus $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Conversely, suppose $f$ is increasing and uniformly continuous.  Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ witnessing uniform continuity.  Suppose $x-y<\delta$.  If $x\geq y$, then $|x-y|<\delta$ and so $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ and thus $f(x)-f(y)<\epsilon$.  If $x<y$, then $f(x)\leq f(y)$ since $f$ is increasing so $f(x)-f(y)\leq 0<\epsilon$.  Thus in either case, $x-y<\delta$ implies $f(x)-f(y)<\epsilon$ and your condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.                                                                            
What if the epsilon is not any arbitrary ? i.e for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exist a $\delta \gt 0$ such that the condition hold ?